# Call virtual method over multiple inheritance leves

Tags: c#, inheritance, virtual, radix

What is the easiest way in c#, to directly call the virtual method implementation in multiple levels of inheritance? I only know `base` for this, but with `base` it seems that i not call the virtual method, but an overriden. For example:

1. Class A has a virtual method: `public virutal void Do()`
2. Class B overrides the method: `public override void Do()`
3. Class C wants to call the implementation in class A.

The inheritance is like this:

1. `class B : A`
2. `class C : B`

I think this is very easy but i did not get it.

Thank you...

Comment: i think its not possible because you override that method in B class and a class will get Do() from B class

Comment: In duplicated question it is states it's not possible, while it really is.